# bootstrap.yml file not loading in spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config-server

I have a microservice named account-service and also have a bootstrap.yml file In the resources directory to point config server. I realease that when I change config server port in the bootstrap.yml file; it does not recognizes the changes. So, the problem is spring boot app does not load bootstrap.yml file. I use spring-boot 3.2.0 and spring cloud: 2023.0.0. Also, this dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```